# Screen areas get blurry with Nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, graphics, kubuntu

My screen is constantly blurring in areas that are not updated/changing. It looks like the driver is applying some sort of anti-aliasing to the same image over and over again, resulting in static areas getting blurrier with every new frame.

I've had this issue for about one year now and on various distros / desktop environments, but it only occurred occasionally right after closing a game and went away after a reboot. That same thing happened again yesterday, but rebooting didn’t fix it this time. I already tried rolling back from driver 435 to 430 (which used to work), but that didn’t help either. The nouveau driver seems to work just fine though, my Windows installation doesn’t have any problems either. Here are my current specs:

- Kubuntu 19.10 w/ Linux 5.3.0-26-generic (64-bit)
- Nvidia GTX 1070ti (driver 430.50, had the same problem with 435.xx)
- KDE Plasma 5.16.5

I made a [Google Drive share](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Dr0_jBIzS9jVqRQSd85rAQ5Sd0dHZdnq) containing an nvidia bug report log and a video showing the blurry effect (I made sure there are no visible compression artifacts, this is what my screen actually looks like).

How can I get rid of this strange behavior? If you need any more information, just let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

I have the identical setup referenced.

I had this blurring problem and traced it to enabling FXAA in Nvidia settings. Originally I enabled this feature out of curiosity and noticed no difference. I then forgot about it. Yesterday I applied available updates and suddenly this blurring problem presented. After much futile struggle, I recalled fiddling with the Nvidia settings and returned there. It says pretty plainly that enabling FXAA disables antialiasing, yet in my Kubuntu settings I had antialiasing enabled. For some reason just disabling FXAA did not restore expected behaviour -- I had to change the Application settings to Enhance, and then the blurring disappeared. It was then fine to go back to the default Application Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue after enabling FXAA, i disabled it, and it got fixed.

but still laptop is still slow after installing i3 regolith on popos (ubuntu 20.04)

Intel i7
Nvidia RTX 2060
32GB RAM
1TB SSD

Switching tabs in firefox sometimes still renders old tabs fragments.

Answer (score 0):

This setting somehow affects Firefox 89+ too. See this issue for more details
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1717453

Thankfully, disabling FXAA solves the problem.